# Downloading files in python in HTTP/1.0

Tags: python, download, mechanize

I am  using the mechanize library in python to download large files. I am using mechanize to retrieve data in a form .

The problem with downloading too many files simultaneously using python is that my system memory (RAM) quickly gets used up.

One way I can think of, to reduce memory usage, is to download partial content of the files and keep saving them to the hard disk. But the internet server that I am downloading the files from uses HTTP/1.0. So when I add the Range header to the download request, Range: bytes=0-8192 , The server returns the file *starting* from the 8192th byte.

Is there something wrong with the header I have added or partial content download is not possible for HTTP/1.0 ?

Is there any other way to reduce the memory usage of the download script ?

Here's, the python code to download the file :

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

webpage = <url>
br.addheaders = [("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"), ("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5"),("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"),("DNT","1")]
br.open(webpage)

br.select_form(name='receive')

fl_nm = "test.pdf"

br.addheaders = [("Range", "bytes=0-8192")]
response = br.submit() # submits the form, just like if you clicked the submit button
fileObj = open(direc+'/'+fl_nm,"w") # open for write
fileObj.write(response.read())
fileObj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is like a file handle, so you can read it chunk-by-chunk:

```
response = br.open('...')

with open('output.ext', 'wb') as handle:
    for chunk in iter((lambda: response.read(4096)), ''):
        handle.write(chunk)
```

So instead of reading the entire file into memory and then writing it back out, you read it 4096 bytes at a time.

Comment: I am submitting a form and then retrieving the file. Is that option available in br.submit() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def output_page(file_name, url, chunk=1024):
    f = open(file_name,'wb') # open file
    page = urllib.urlopen(url) # open webpage
    s = page.read(chunk) # read the first chunk
    while s: # once the page is read, s == ''
        f.write(s) # write data
        s = page.read(chunk) # and read the next chunk
```